# Show name property of associated external content type in list view

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

On a page, I show an external list. The underlying external content type has an association to another external content type. I built this with sharepoint designer. In the list, the associated type is shown with it´s **ID** which is not very helpful for the user.
I would like to know if I can set the property that is displayed, e.g. the name.

I can influence the field displayed in the *view/edit form* by setting this field as title in the summary view of sharepoint designer, section "fields". (Note, "Set as title" is found in the upper ribbon.) However, this does not change the field displayed in the list, which is still the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you need to build a view on the table which contains all table columns plus the additional columns that should be shown. Important: All column names must match exactly.
- Based on this view, a ReadList and a ReadItem operation have to be added to the external content type and are set as default operations. Important: the additional fields must be set "read-only" in the operations if a create and update is intended.

Comment: I just wanted to say, 2 days pulling out my hair until I found this.  The fact that the columns must match exactly on the view, and the additional fields must be set as "read-only" was the key.  Thank you! (I would give you extra votes for coming back and answering your own question if I could...bravo!)

Comment: To be clear, are you performing a join in your new view, or are you actually using SharePoint to pull the data?